# jQuery / javascript changing element on dragstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

How to assignment (transfer , ...) dragstart event of a element to other element?

**HTML:**

`<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> draggable </div>`

`<div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)"> droppable </div>`

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        $('.drag-panel').css({"top":event.pageY-70+'px',"left":event.pageX-70+'px'});
        Mouse.x = event.pageX;
        Mouse.y = event.pageY;
    });
});
function drag(event){ 
   event.preventDefault(); 
   var panel = $('.drag-panel')[0];             
   $(panel).css({"top":Mouse.y-70+'px',"left":Mouse.x-70+'px',"display":"block"});
   //and continue dragging with $(panel) ??
}

function dragover(event){
    alert('dragover'); 
}
```

is there a way to change dragging element when `drag()` is called ?